# Roll fair die until you get (1)

Tags: probability

Roll a fair dice until you get (1). Let X = # of rolls needed. Similarly, for a second die, Y = # of rolls needed to get (1).

For M = min(X,Y) find the pmf and E(M).

This is a sample problem, i have no idea how to solve for the pmf of M. can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\min(X,Y)$. Then $M\gt k$ if and only if both dice refuse to show a $1$ a total of $k$ times in a row. The probability of this is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^k\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^k$. Thus
$$\Pr(M\gt k)=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2k}.$$
To finish, note that
$$\Pr(M=k)=\Pr(M\gt k-1)-\Pr(M\gt k).$$

For the expectation, there are many approaches. One can sum the series, using the expectation of the geometric to simplify calculations. I would prefer to use a conditional expectation argument, conditioning on the result of the first toss on each die.

**Another way:** We toss a red die and a green die repeatedly, and stop when at least one of the dice shows a $1$. The probability that at least one die shows a $1$ is easily computed, it is $\frac{11}{36}$. So $M$ has **geometric distribution** with parameter $p=\frac{11}{36}$. If you know the pmf and expectation of a general geometric, you can write down the answers immediately.

Comment: i understand your answer from M's point of view. can you please help me understand between M and X,Y?

Comment: $M$ is the "smaller" of $X$ and $Y$. So we are tossing a red die and a green die repeatedly, and we will be happy if we get a $1$ on either one. So $M$ is the number of tosses until we are happy.

Comment: $M=\min(X,Y)$ hence $\begin{align}\mathsf P(M>k) & = \mathsf P(X>k\cap Y>k) \\ & = \mathsf P(X>k)\times\mathsf P(Y>k) \\ & = (\tfrac 5 6)^k\times (\tfrac 5 6)^k \\ & = (\tfrac 5 6)^{2k}\end{align}$

Comment: I think i figure it out. when i solved it out i got 

P(M=k) = 1/6 * (5/6)^(2k-2) since i am solving until one of then actually hits 1 (hence the 1/6). does this make sense?

Comment: It is fairly close to right. If you use either of my two approaches, you will get $\frac{11}{36}\cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2k-2}$.

Comment: wouldn't 11/36 be in the solution when both X and Y give a positive result on turn k? but since we are looking for the minimum, at turn roll k, only X or Y must roll a (1). the roll of the other is irrelevant and thus P = 6/6?

Comment: @ava, $11/36$ is the probability that of two rolled dice on a turn *at least one* of them shows a `1`.  The complement is that neither show a `1`.  $1-\mathsf P(A\neq 1\cap B\neq 1) = 1-(5/6)^2=11/36$